# OpenMPI already installed in OS X?

Tags: macos, xcode, development

I've been looking for MPI for OS X and some websites say that it is already installed in OS X (since 10.5).

Could someone point out where is it installed? I cannot find `mpicc` nor `mpirun`. Or should I build OpenMPI from code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither `mpicc` nor `mpirun` are installed on a stock Mountain Lion system nor present with Xcode v5 or lower.

The [homebrew packaging system](http://brew.sh) has a trivially simple install (v2.0.1):

```
brew install open-mpi
```

You could also build your OpenMPI from code:

- https://sites.google.com/site/dwhipp/tutorials/installing-open-mpi-on-mac-os-x

It appears from this [article, that Lion dropped the inclusion of a build of OpenMPI](http://www.compmath.com/blog/tag/mac-os-x/) - but I'd go with the instructions above rather than the MacPorts version if you don't already use MacPorts.

Comment: This link is broken. Could you explain how to install openmpi on osx in your reply?

Comment: @kilojoules Thanks for noticing the redirect. The link wasn't broken, but the content is permanently moved. I've added hombrew since it works much better for me and also changed one of the links to keep them sparkling and take you directly to the content instead of a "we've moved" page.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `gcc` and `g++` are at least version 5.0 (eg. `brew install gcc5 --with-fortran --without-multilib`)

Download the openmpi tar.gz file here: http://www.open-mpi.org/

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar zxvf openmpi...tar.gz
cd openmpi....
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/openmpi
make
sudo make install (enter password)
```

Now add

```
export MPI_DIR=/usr/local/openmpi
export PATH=/usr/local/openmpi/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/openmpi/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

To the bottom of `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Nice! Do you find building from source to be better than just `brew install openmpi` in some manner?

Comment: @bmike mpif90 resulted in `No underlying compiler was specified in the wrapper compiler data file`  after I tried the brew method on my personal computer.

Comment: Got it. If you want to ask a follow on question and link it here or ping me in comments, I'll have a stab at getting you around that roadblock if the solution eludes you.